# Can't locate local key file asked by parity to sign a transaction

Tags: parity, private-key, parity-signer

When I use NODE-RED enviroment to send transaction using Parity, the signer doesn't ask only for the password as usual but also for the local key file, which I can't locate in my laptop (I'm looking in the directory /home/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum).

[image: Parity signer asking for local key ile]

Why does this happen? Where can I find this file?

Thanks in advance,

Simone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple possible reasons.

- From your screenshot, the account doesn't have a name, so most probably it's not present on the accounts list. I assume that either it's from a closed vault or **the request was issued via RPC**, so probably you sent it manually, and the account is simply unknown to parity.
- The signer thinks it's an external account. This generally means that the signer's account selector allowed you to select an account that isn't available for Parity currently. This **sometimes happens by closing a vault** in one tab while using a DApp in another.
- If you created it this account just right now via RPC, then it **may just needs a page reload**. The account list in the redux state doesn't track accounts creation/deletion except when in its own tab.
- But account in a vault is the most plausible explanation. **Unlock your vault** and let me know if you could figure it out.

*Disclosure: I work for Parity.*

Comment: Indeed it was due to the second reason you mentioned. Thank you for your help.